# python remove repeated values in set

Tags: python, list, dictionary, map-function

I have a set which looks like this:

```
my_set  = {
  [
      {
         "sample_id": "read1", 
         "seg_1": None, 
         "lukM-F": "D", 
         "23s_SA": None, 
         "see": None, 
         "sed": "ND"
      }, 
      {
         "sample_id": "read2", 
         "seg_1": None, 
         "lukM-F": "ND", 
         "23s_SA": None, 
         "see": "D", 
         "sed": "ND"
      }, 
      {
         "sample_id": "read3", 
         "seg_1": None, 
         "lukM-F": "D", 
         "23s_SA": None, 
         "see": "ND", 
         "sed": "None"
      }
  ]
}
```

I want to remove the keys that have the value 'None' throughout the string. For example, example: If "None" is the value of the key "seg_1" in each and every sample_id (read1 AND read2 AND read3) then remove the key altogether. If there is one "None" in "seg_1", say in read1, and the other two sample_id are not "None" then keep "seg_1" and its values. So I like to end up with the following:

```
my_set  = {
  [
      {
         "sample_id": "read1",  
         "lukM-F": "D", 
         "see": None, 
         "sed": "ND"
      }, 
      {
         "sample_id": "read2", 
         "lukM-F": "ND", 
         "see": "D", 
         "sed": "ND"
      }, 
      {
         "sample_id": "read3", 
         "lukM-F": "D", 
         "see": "ND", 
         "sed": "None"
      }
  ]
}
```

Note that the seg_1 and 23s_SA have now been removed as they have a value of 'None' throughout all sample_ids.

I have spent a long time trying to do this but with no success.  I have finally though of converting the set to dict and then lists and then loop through all lists and remove all items in all lists that contain None throughout.

```
number_of_samples = len(my_set)
each_sample_list = [[] for i in range(0, number_of_samples)]

n = 0

for data_in_dict in my_set:
  for k,val in data_in_dict.items():
    each_sample_list[n].append([k,val])
  if n == number_of_samples:
    break
  else:
    print each_sample_list[n]
    n += 1
```

I thought of using itertools izip to loop through multiple lists but not sure if this is going to work.  Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Your "StringIO" is actually a `set` containing a single `list` containing three `dict`. Nothing like a `StringIO` object (https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html)

Comment: Your `my_stringio` is not a valid python expression.

Comment: Your `my_set` still isn't a valid Python set.

Comment: How can you have (mutable) list in set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create counter, then remove all needed keys:

```
import collections
import itertools

source = [ 
  {
     "sample_id": "read1", 
     "seg_1": None, 
     "lukM-F": "D", 
     "23s_SA": None, 
     "see": None, 
     "sed": "ND"
  }, 
  {
     "sample_id": "read2", 
     "seg_1": None, 
     "lukM-F": "ND", 
     "23s_SA": None, 
     "see": "D", 
     "sed": "ND"
  }, 
  {
     "sample_id": "read3", 
     "seg_1": None, 
     "lukM-F": "D", 
     "23s_SA": None, 
     "see": "ND", 
     "sed": "None"
  }
]

size = len(source)

# for python2 you should use iteritems() method
iterators_chain = itertools.chain(*[x.items() for x in source])
counter = collections.Counter(iterators_chain)

for (key, val), count in counter.items():
    if count == size and val is None:
        for x in source:
            x.pop(key)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `my_set` isn't a valid set, since set items must be hashable, and lists are not hashable. But anyway...

Here's a way to do it that doesn't require any imports. It uses sets to determine which keys to keep.

```
my_stuff = [
    {
        "sample_id": "read1", 
        "seg_1": None, 
        "lukM-F": "D", 
        "23s_SA": None, 
        "see": None, 
        "sed": "ND"
    }, 
    {
        "sample_id": "read2", 
        "seg_1": None, 
        "lukM-F": "ND", 
        "23s_SA": None, 
        "see": "D", 
        "sed": "ND"
    }, 
    {
        "sample_id": "read3", 
        "seg_1": None, 
        "lukM-F": "D", 
        "23s_SA": None, 
        "see": "ND", 
        "sed": None
    }
]

allkeys = set(k for d in my_stuff for k in d)
goodkeys = set(k for k in allkeys if any(d.get(k) for d in my_stuff))
badkeys = allkeys - goodkeys
for d in my_stuff:
    for k in badkeys:
        del d[k]

for d in my_stuff:
    print(d)
```

**output**

```
{'lukM-F': 'D', 'see': None, 'sed': 'ND', 'sample_id': 'read1'}
{'lukM-F': 'ND', 'see': 'D', 'sed': 'ND', 'sample_id': 'read2'}
{'lukM-F': 'D', 'see': 'ND', 'sed': None, 'sample_id': 'read3'}
```

Those `set(...)` constructions for `allkeys` and `goodkeys` can be replaced with set comprehensions in modern versions of Python, but I'm on Python 2.6.6 on this ancient machine.

---

An alternative way to build the `allkeys` set is

```
allkeys = set()
for d in my_stuff:
    allkeys.update(d.keys())
```

Although it's more code, it runs faster because `.update` is processing the whole key collection of a `dict` at C speed, whereas the other way has to loop over the keys at Python speed. Of course, if you can guarantee that the set of keys in each `dict` of the list will always be the same then this can be optimized even further.

Answer (score 2):

Taking advantage that the keys must be `None` in all of the `dict` inside the `list`

```
bkeys = [k for k, v in next(iter(my_stuff), {}).items() if v is None]

bkeys = [k for k in bkeys if all(d[k] is None for d in my_stuff)]

my_stuff = [{k: v for k, v in d.items() if k not in bkeys} for d in my_stuff]
```

A printout of the new `my_stuff`:

```
{'see': None, 'sed': 'ND', 'lukM-F': 'D', 'sample_id': 'read1'}
{'see': 'D', 'sed': 'ND', 'lukM-F': 'ND', 'sample_id': 'read2'}
{'see': 'ND', 'sed': None, 'lukM-F': 'D', 'sample_id': 'read3'}
```

Without `dict` comprehensions just change the last line to:

```
my_stuff = [dict(((k, v) for k, v in d.items() if k not in bkeys)) for d in my_stuff]
```

**Edited** to only work with the `None` keys of the 1st item if present.

Comment: Your `keys` contains only the keys from the 1st list in `my_stuff`. So why not simply `keys = my_stuff[0].keys()`?

Comment: Because `[0]` is not guaranteed. I already had that in mind and was looking for a combination of expressions that would achieve only looking into the 1st element if "present"